# when I use the django function object.filter ,the python's handle increased,how can i resolve this?

Tags: django, handle-leak

I use the `WIN7 32 System`,`Django 1.8.13`, `Python 2.7`.

When I use functions like `xxx.object.all()` or `xxx.object.filter('xx')`,the python's handle number will increase.

It seems that it used `Class QuerySet`, then the handle number will increase. Even if,I just use the `admin-site` to manage the DataBase. The handle leak also will happen.

How can I release it or resolve it ?

Comment: what's handle do you mean?

Comment: I mean the python program's handles.If you open the Django administration and go into the Users.Then you press F5,and open the windows task manager ,you can find the handles number will increase.

Comment: Would you mind tell more about your question?

Comment: of course.what do you want to know?  @Windsooon

Comment: Please add the screenshot to show what handles number really are.

Answer (score 0):

It seems taht I use sqlite3,the handle will not increase.But when i use the mysql 5.6.16,the handles' number will increase. And the Mysql Server was default configuration.

mysql5.5
mysql-python 1.2.5

setting.py:

```
DATABASES = {
'default':{
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME':'pcdata',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'supcondcs',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '',
}
```

}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9wuf.png)

Comment: I think the number of handle means how many requests has been handled by the httpd service. It's not related with the database but only with http requests sent to the httpd service. If you visit a page of admin console of django, the number will be increased more than 1, since there also other resources will be fetched by the browser like css/js files.

Comment: thank you very much. I had resolved it. It cause by the DB connection. Every DB connections made by http requests will make the number increase.So I make a longtime connection,that the DB connection will not be too much.